# Android and video streaming - How can do it?

Tags: android

This is my problem. I have on my hosting an avi video file and I want that the user of my android application can display it in streaming on your smartphone.

There are two way.

1) Convert this file in mp4 format and visual it into my application with MediaPlayer

2) Control that on user's device there is Rockplayer and then to use it for display this avi file.

What the good way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this [link](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9540). It is very good example for Android Media Streaming.

Media streaming on Android devices using the VideoView object available in the android.widget package. This widget allows audio or video playback local or global resources.

Answer (score 0):

Choose option 1. You don't want to "sponsor" third-party applications such as RockPlayer when building your own app. What if the user doesn't have internet connection by the time he's trying to use your app? And he hasn't downloaded RockPlayer previously? As much as possible you want your app to be independent of other market apps, especially those you do not own.